# Vaadin 8 TreeGrid - is it possible to have multi select for leaf/child elements, and have parents not selectable?

Tags: vaadin

Vaadin 8 makes use of grids. A tree grid is where root elements can have leaf elements attached to them (children). In my case, i want the grid features of multi select - giving each row a checkbox to allow selecting multiple rows, but i do not want the user to be able to select parent/root elements in the grid. How do you disable root elements in a treegrid from the multi select, and only allow multi select of leaf elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't prevent selection exactly, but you can immediately deselect any unwanted selection when it occurs:

```java
        treeGrid.addSelectionListener(e -> {
            Set<HierarchicalBean> allSelectedItems = e.getAllSelectedItems();
            Set<HierarchicalBean> toRemove = new HashSet<>();
            for (HierarchicalBean b : allSelectedItems) {
                if (!b.hasParent()) {
                    toRemove.add(b);
                }
            }
            for (HierarchicalBean beanToRemove : toRemove) {
                treeGrid.deselect(beanToRemove);
            }
        });
```

Comment: i take it you can't prevent the checkbox from showing next to root elements? Ideally I'd like to remove the checkbox from these root element rows,

Comment: Not directly. You can probably do some halfway workaround with styles; if use `treeGrid.setStyleGenerator()`, you can add a css class name to the specific rows and in there, you could target the element `v-treegrid-selection-checkbox` and maybe hide it with `display: none; pointer-events: none`, but that's still not going to be perfect (e.g. keyboard selection will still work).

Comment: thanks for you help. I'll use a combination of both for this,. cheers